# Rolling a dice and tossing a coin (Probability)

Tags: probability

Question: A person throws a pair of dice. If the sum of the numbers on the dice is even, then the person tosses a coin. What is the probability of him getting a head?

**My approaches:-**

**Approach 1:-**

Since the possible sum of 2 dice would be in the range of [2,12]

P(H) = P(even) * P(head|even) = 6/11 * 1/2 = 3/11

**Approach 2:-**

Listing down the sample space = { (2,H),(2,T),3,(4,H),(4,T),5....,11,(12,H),(12,T) } this set

has 17 outcomes possible of which the outcomes having H are 6 , so the probability is turning out

to be 6/17

Which method would be correct ? and what are the mistakes involved in the approaches  ?

Comment: Note: the sums of two dice are not uniformly distributed. There are $36 = 6 \cdot 6$ possible pairs of two dice, and e.g. rolling a sum of $2$ occurs exactly once with $(1,1)$ but rolling a sum of $3$ occurs in two ways with $(1,2)$ or $(2,1)$, so it's twice as likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe both methods are incorrect.

**The Problem with Method 1**

$P(even)=6/11$ is incorrect. You are correct that there are $11$ possible sums you can roll on two dice, but not all of them are equally likely. For example, there are many more ways to roll an $8$ with two dice than to roll a $2$. The right probability is actually $P(even)=1/2$, which you can see by listing out all $36$ possible pairs of dice rolls.

**The problem with Method 2**

You are correct that the sample space for this problem has $17$ possible outcomes. However, not all of them are equally likely.

**The Correct Method**

$P(H) = P(even) * P(head|even)=1/2*1/2=1/4$